# How do you make a React JS click handler update the DOM when executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, rendering

I am in the final stages of finishing a demo app using React JS, rendering data in a table. When you hover over an item in the status column, a popup div appears and you can click on one of 3 options in a list. Once one of the items is clicked, I am able to get the click handler to run, but I can't figure out how to cause the DOM to change to show the newly clicked Status and to change the Update field with a new, current, date.

I am currently trying to change the source data and re-render, but am having no luck. Could somebody please tell me the idiomatic and simplest way to do this in React?

Here is my click Handler:

```
     statusDropdownClickHandler: function(e) {
          var el = e.currentTarget.closest("tr").firstChild;
          var title = el.innerHTML;
          var newStatus = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;

          e.currentTarget.closest("td").innerHtml = newStatus;

          for (i=0; i < requests.length; i++) {
            if (requests[i].title === title) {
                    var newDate = new Date();

                    requests[i].status = newStatus;
                requests[i].updated_at = String(newDate);
            }
          }
          e.currentTarget.closest("td").firstChild.style.display = 'none';
          this.render();
        },
```

And Here is the function to render this section of the page:

```
renderRows: function() {
        var self = this;
      var shouldIRender = (row) => 
        (this.state.filter === row.status || this.state.filter === "");

      var sortedRequests = requests.sort(function(a,b) { 
        return new Date(b.updated_at).getTime() - new Date(a.updated_at).getTime();
      });

      for (i=0; i < sortedRequests.length; i++) {
        sortedRequests[i].created_at = sortedRequests[i].created_at.split(" ")[0];
        sortedRequests[i].updated_at = sortedRequests[i].updated_at.split(" ")[0];
      }

        return sortedRequests.filter(shouldIRender).map(function(row, j) {
        return <tr key={j}>
                 <td style={tdStyle}>{row.title}</td>
                 <td style={statusStyle} 
                 onMouseOver={self.statusHoverHandler}  
                 onMouseOut={self.statusBlurHandler} 
                 onChange={self.statusChangeHandler}>
                 <div style={statusDropdownStyle}>
                  {statusItems.map(function(item, j) {
                    return (
                    <div key={j} style={dropdownDivStyle} 
 //see here ----->    onClick={self.statusDropdownClickHandler}
                      onMouseOver={self.statusDropdownHoverHandler} 
                      onMouseOut={self.statusDropdownBlurHandler}>{item.text}</div>
                  )})}
                 </div>
                 {row.status}</td>
                 <td style={tdStyle}>{row.created_at}</td>
                 <td style={tdStyle}>{row.updated_at}</td>
                 <td style={tdStyle}><a href="#" onClick={self.delete}>delete</a></td>
               </tr>                             
        })
    },
```

And here is [a link to a current JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssbdnbw8/20/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way is to change your state in the event handler, and then that will trigger a render.  Based on the current state, render your DOM elements and styles in the render method.

Comment: I thought I understood what that meant, but inside of my click handler I am changing the requests data array and nothing is happening. Inside of the same handler I am calling re-render and am manually trying to reset innerHTML on the status td element that I want to affect. Nothing is working. Could you please give me an example of how to do this correctly?

Comment: Sure, take a look at `selectChangeHandler`, I helped you with that earlier.  We're manipulating the state, and when we call setState, a render is automatically triggered.  In the render function, we now this this.state.filter, which contains our new filter.  Looking at your code there's many errors, `onclick` should be `onClick` there is a difference. `statusDropdownClickHandler` doesn't define `e`, `e.current.target` should be `e.currentTarget`  that should get you going.  Again, take a look at how we handle state change for the filter.  Move any DOM manipulation to the render method.

Comment: Okay, I feel like I'm on the cusp here. And I feel like you might be looking at an old version of my fiddle, cause I've taken most of this stuff into account (onClick, etc.)

Is it necessary for me to bring the requests data array into the initial state so that when I update it with `this.setState({requests: update-code-here});` it will auto re-render?

Comment: Yes  you'll want to have an empty requests array in your initial state.  Then use this.state.requests in your render function to create the elements you want.

Comment: Sidenote: in your handler, you are directly updating DOM in  `e.currentTarget.closest("td").innerHtml = newStatus;` and `e.currentTarget.closest("td").firstChild.style.display = 'none';`. This is really not a good idea in react. Better to put these variables in state, and include the rendering of newStatus and style in your `render()` function.

Comment: Ok, good advice. I'll refactor. When I select a filter from the drop down and look at a subtable view, there is a strange bug that I can't figure out. when I update the status, it re-renders the the app but is causing the next status down to update as well. Maybe your observation has something to do with why this is happening. I am calling setState to make the render happen automatically, but it is not as straight forward as updating a string, like my filter variable, as I'm dealing with for loops crawling nodes in a nested data-structure...